# An error occur while loading from c:\temp.rdp

Tags: c#, .net, exception, rdp

I am trying to open RDP from ASP.NET application.
i created a method to create .rdp file with connection parameters but when tried to run this method i got the following error :

> An error occur while loading from c:\temp.rdp

Here's my code:

```
public static void RdcTest(string server, string domain, string username, string password)
{
    string encyptedPassword = "";

    //Calling the CryptUnprotectData API to encypt the password, 
    //Read this link for how to do this:
    //http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic21805.aspx

    string filename = @"c:\temp.rdp";
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {                
            sw.WriteLine("screen mode id:i:2");
            sw.WriteLine("desktopwidth:i:1440");
            sw.WriteLine("desktopheight:i:900");
            sw.WriteLine("full address:s:" + server);
            sw.WriteLine("username:s:" + username);
            sw.WriteLine("domain:s:" + domain);
            sw.WriteLine("password 51:b:" + encyptedPassword);
        }

        Process rdcProcess = new Process();

        string strExE = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strExE;
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = filename;
        rdcProcess.Start();
    }
}
```

any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: What kind of error? Be more specific

Comment: i tested this method at first in console application but i got message error (just a window message error) saying "An error occur while loading from c:\temp.rdp"

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Even if successful, it will open mstsc.exe on the server, and the user won't see anything happening.

Comment: I should add, the user won't see anything happen, unless the server and the client are the same machine, which is probably true for development, but probably not true for production.

Comment: dear all, look>>> i can from command line to enter smtsc then a window open so i can enter IP and user name and then i can save this file to my PC and finally i can just click this file to run rdp to the destination ,,so why i can not do this from the codeeeeeeeeeeeeee????

Comment: i this example i just try to create .rdp file so what the problem ?

Comment: @RagaeiMahmoud Did you find a solution for this?